# show/hide link cliking on another link AND outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Asking for help:
how to hide a link clicking on another link and outside the DIV.
Here is my example, which hide a link clicking outside the div:

jsfiddle.net/xbJ6u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change layer id to class like this

```
<div id="layer">
```

to

```
<div class="layer">
```

*Note: ID's must be unique*

Then on click hide layer

```
  $('.link').click(function (e) {
           $('.layer').hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbJ6u/3/)